# How to split resource under date in react big calendar

Tags: reactjs, calendar

[Calendar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cybqG.png)
I am using react big calendar.

I am able to get calendar like in image.

But I needed to split under date.

Is there any property I can try to split?

In FullCalendar component ,there is resourceunderdate=true.

In react big calendar is there any option?

I have refered the component documentation.
But there is no property available

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.